# Nested SQL query not working referring two different databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

Query:

```
SELECT xid 
FROM db2.pat_info 
WHERE xid IN (SELECT DISTINCT xid 
              FROM db1.audit 
              WHERE FUNCTION IN ('ABC','PQR') 
              AND xid NOT LIKE 'test%' 
              AND status = 1 
              AND ques_responded = 9) 
AND fname IS NOT NULL 
AND t_id IN (11,12)
```

I am a beginner to SQL and facing an issue in executing the query mentioned above. The inner query is executing as expected but when integrated with outer query then I am not getting any result to the query.

If both the queries are executed individually then getting the result as expected.

The 'FUNCTION' column mentioned in inner query is 'function' in the table. It can't be changed as it's old implementation.

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: No rows match your conditions.

Comment: When i am executing the inner query individually and taking the result and providing the same as input to outer query then it's working fine and i'm getting results as expected.

Comment: Not getting any result to the query here means the execution remains in process for long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` can be quite inefficient.  Switch to `EXISTS` or move to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT pi.xid 
FROM db2.pat_info pi JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT xid 
      FROM db1.audit 
      WHERE FUNCTION IN ('ABC', 'PQR') AND
            xid NOT LIKE 'test%' AND
            status = 1 AND
            ques_responded = 9
     )  a
     ON pi.xid = a.xid
WHERE pi.fname IS NOT NULL AND pi.t_id IN (11, 12);
```

In some versions of MySQL, the subquery is re-run for every row in the outer table.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! This worked for me. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happening while you are merging the query, but if you have  performance concern then i would suggest  to use `exists` instead of `in` clause

```
SELECT xid 
FROM db2.pat_info p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM db1.audit 
              WHERE xid = P.xid AND FUNCTION IN ('ABC','PQR') AND 
                    xid NOT LIKE 'test%' AND 
                    status = 1 AND ques_responded = 9) AND 
fname IS NOT NULL AND t_id IN (11,12);
```